# Simple Dependency injection not working

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

It's the first time I have to use Dependency Injection and I'm a little confused.

I don't really understand how it works.

I have tried on a simple example :

```
public class StockResponse extends Response
{
    @Inject BrandService $brand;

    public List<StockResponseItem> stock;

    public StockThresholdResponse()
    {
        stock = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static StockThresholdResponse create(List<DataItem> data)
    {
        StockResponse stock= new StockResponse();

        for (ThresholdCheckAggregate data: d)
        {
            StockResponseItem item = new StockResponseItem();

            item.id = d.thresholdId;
            item.brand = str.$brand.byId(d.brand);

            str.stockThresholds.add(item);
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

But when I use my `create()` method, I get a null pointer exception for `$brand`.

I think I have misunderstood how DI works but I can't find my error.

Comment: Are you using a DI container? Maybe you should inject the brand dependency using constructor injection, i.e., add a BrandService parameter in the class constructor a then save it to the $brand field from there

Comment: a DI container ? I'm using play that, I think, manage this for me...
I have tried your solution but the statement `new StockResponse()` failed because of lack of parameter...

Comment: Where do you create the StockReponse instance? You should create it in the [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). You should do something like new StockReponse(new BrandService()). This is called [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/). I have never used the play framework and don't know how it is used.

Comment: It use Guice framework for automatic injection

Comment: If you don't want to use Pure DI, which seems the case, maybe you should use the @Inject annotation on the constructor, and then there should be a way to create the StockResponse via the container, not via new

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/GettingStarted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar difficulties to understand how DI (Guice out of Java EE) works. In simple words Guice must have  chance to modify You object, for example:

- assist by construction usually. 
  You ask Guice "can You create my object" `injector.getInstance(cls)`, then Guice is creating object for You, solving field or constructor annotation

In normal (non Java EE) environment Yoy never call classic constructor, You ask by second hand.

- other method. 
  Few library / frameworks have integration with Guice (Apache Wicket I personally like) with "creation listeners" on some types of objects. Hard work of DI is hidden for Your eyes, but is executed.
- Java EE lets say better EE programmers than me  :(

In consequence Yoy don't give chance to inject anything, is null

Professionals sorry that I say at blondie level. That is way like I discovered DI few years ago

Correction to code. Not

```
StockResponse stock= new StockResponse();
```

but

```
 mod = .... // Module 
   injector = Guice.createInjector(mod); // global or almost global 
...
   injector.getInstance(StockResponse.class);
```

EDIT: intentionally I don't answer "how to write Guice module", assume this is other, long story

Answer (score 0):

This could work, assuming BrandService is either a concrete class or if it's an interface, you have provided a binding for it to a concrete class elsewhere in your DI configuration (say a module in Guice or Spring @Configuration). I do see one obvious `NullPointerException` with `str` variable. Did you mean to do this?

```
item.brand = stock.$brand.byId(d.brand);
```